# Does iPhone support "greying out" inactive controls?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, user-interface

I have a control that goes inactive under some conditions in my iPhone app. I can [setUserInteractionEnabled: NO] on it and it doesn't respond to touches. Its appearance does not change however. Other environments I am familiar with "grey out" inactive controls. I wonder what is the idiomatic way to hint to the user that the control is inactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIControl` (the parent class of all the common controls) has an `enabled` property that you can set to `NO`.

What it does is dependent on which subclass you're dealing with, and whether you've, say, used custom images for the various states.